# Iterating over pandas DataFrame with identical columns header

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to iterate through rows and columns of the Pandas DataFrame and write that result in a new DataFrame if some condition is met. I am able to iterate on the following DataFrame which has different names for row and column.

```
     W0O5  W1O5  W2O5  W3O5
W0O5   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
W1O5   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
W2O5   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0
W3O5   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

I used the following approach

```
for i in pandas_df.index:
    for j in pandas_df.columns:
        print(i, j)
        print(pandas_df.at[i, j])
        if pandas_df.at[i, j] ==1:
            single_pandas_df.at['WO5', 'WO5_corner'] =1
```

where single_pandas_df  is the new DataFrame I created, on which I want to add the value at corresponding row and column.

However, when I try to iterate through  DataFrame containing identical header for row and columns as below:

```
     WO5  WO5  WO5  WO5
WO5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
WO5  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
WO5  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
WO5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

I get the AttributeError saying

AttributeError: 'BlockManager' object has no attribute 'T'

I know the error is due to duplicate column names. I was curious is there any way to handle such case in pandas. I have all of my DataFrames as in the second case and I need to get the values of each index from row and column.

Thanks in advance.

Update after Yolos comment:
Actually I have many such DataFrames as below

```
      DyO7  DyO7  DyO6  DyO7  DyO7  DyO6
DyO7   0.0   3.0   1.0   2.0   1.0   0.0
DyO7   3.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
DyO6   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
DyO7   2.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   3.0   1.0
DyO7   1.0   0.0   1.0   3.0   0.0   0.0
DyO6   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0
```

and next one as

```
       TaO6  TaO6
TaO6   0.0   1.0
TaO6   1.0   0.0
```

In these DataFrames 1 ,2 and 3 represents the corner, edge and face sharing. So if (i,j) item in the DataFrame is 1, it goes to "..."_corner, if 2 it goes to edge and 3 goes to face.

my initial single_pandas DataFrame looks like following

```
       DyO6_corner  DyO6_edge  DyO6_face  DyO7_corner  DyO7_edge  DyO7_face  TaO6_corner  TaO6_edge  TaO6_face  WO5_corner  WO5_edge  WO5_face
DyO6          0.0        0.0        0.0          0.0        0.0        0.0          0.0        0.0        0.0         0.0       0.0       0.0
DyO7          0.0        0.0        0.0          0.0        0.0        0.0          0.0        0.0        0.0         0.0       0.0       0.0
TaO6          0.0        0.0        0.0          0.0        0.0        0.0          0.0        0.0        0.0         0.0       0.0       0.0
WO5           0.0        0.0        0.0          0.0        0.0        0.0          0.0        0.0        0.0         0.0       0.0       0.0
```

As from my above script after updating this single_pandas DataFrame, there will be 1 at ('WO5', 'WO5_corner') and it becomes:

```
      DyO6_corner  DyO6_edge  DyO6_face  DyO7_corner  DyO7_edge  DyO7_face  TaO6_corner  TaO6_edge  TaO6_face  WO5_corner  WO5_edge  WO5_face
DyO6          0.0        0.0        0.0          0.0        0.0        0.0          0.0        0.0        0.0         0.0       0.0       0.0
DyO7          0.0        0.0        0.0          0.0        0.0        0.0          0.0        0.0        0.0         0.0       0.0       0.0
TaO6          0.0        0.0        0.0          0.0        0.0        0.0          0.0        0.0        0.0         0.0       0.0       0.0
WO5           0.0        0.0        0.0          0.0        0.0        0.0          0.0        0.0        0.0         1         0.0       0.0
```

Comment: why can't you rename them?

Comment: Beacuse I need to add those iterated values in the single DataFrame, to which I need to match the header condition. like in the last line of my small script.

Comment: okay, how are you initialising `single_pandas_df` ? you haven't shown that part

Comment: what is your expected out put

Comment: I updated my question after your comments. Thanks.